# undefined reference to avltree_init

Tags: c, function, struct

In code provided by instructor there is:

```
typedef int (*avltree_cmp_fn_t)(const struct avltree_node *, const struct avltree_node *);

int avltree_init(struct avltree *tree, avltree_cmp_fn_t cmp, unsigned long flags);
```

After I define my_cmp function...

```
int my_cmp(const struct avltree_node *a, const struct avltree_node *b)
{
        struct my_struct *p = avltree_container_of(a, my_struct, node);
        struct my_struct *q = avltree_container_of(b, my_struct, node);
        return p->key - q->key;
}
```

and pass it as a parameter to avltree_init...

```
avltree_init(&tree, my_cmp, 0);
```

I get:

```
undefined reference to `avltree_init(avltree*, int (*)(avltree_node const*, avltree_node const*), unsigned long)'
```

Could someone explain, please, why it happens and where did I make a mistake?
Thanks!

Comment: And where do you *define* the `avltree_init`?

Comment: I don't actually do it myself. It's give in avl.c int avltree_init(struct avltree *tree, avltree_cmp_fn_t cmp, unsigned long flags)
{
 if (flags)
  return -1;
 tree->root = NULL;
 tree->cmp_fn = cmp;
 tree->height = -1;
 tree->first = NULL;
 tree->last = NULL;
 return 0;
}

Comment: And when you link your project, do you include the object file generated from the `avl.c` file? You *do* build with the `avl.c` source file?

Comment: there is libtree.h header file and it contains all functions' signatures. It's included in avl.c and I also included it to the file where resides my main method.

Comment: Be careful defining a comparison function using subtraction like that. For example, what happens when `p->key` is `INT_MAX` and `q->key` is `-1`? Probably not what you actually want.  It's safer to do: `return (p->key < q->key ? -1 : p->key != q->key);`

Comment: Or, for better performance it's possible to use (p->key > q->key) - (p->key < q->key)

Answer (score 0):

It seems from the error message that you're not linking with the file that contains the avltree_init function. You need to link all files, including the file containing that function, to your final application. This error comes from the linking phase, not from the compiling phase.

Furthermore, I see from your error message that you're using a C++ compiler for C code. You don't need to do that: it would be more optimal to use a C compiler.